# SQL query to SELECT and replace only one column value with out defining the other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to do a select, but I need to replace one column's value out.  The table has 25 columns, and I wanted to make this readable with out listing all columns to do the replacement of one column from another table.  Here is what i did that does work,

```
SELECT *  
INTO #temp_grouping
FROM [ae_p_phs_e]
WHERE [template_id] = '1010'
    AND [status_code] = 'OPEN'
    AND [shop] = 'SP-STEAM'

-- select row from the temp table for inserting
UPDATE #temp_grouping
SET 
    [description] = [source_data].[description]
FROM 
    [ae_a_asset_e] AS [source_data]
WHERE 
    [source_data].[asset_tag] = [#temp_grouping].[asset_tag]
    AND [source_data].[multitenant_id] = [#temp_grouping].[multitenant_id]

SELECT *
FROM #temp_grouping

--drop the temp table
DROP TABLE #temp_grouping
```

But what are other ways to do this same thing?

#### SAMPLE

```
TABLE A
-------------------------------------------------
|col1  | col2  | description  | .... | nthColumn|
-------------------------------------------------


TABLE B
-------------------------------------------------
|col1  | col2  | description  | .... | nthColumn|
-------------------------------------------------
```

EXAMPLE Data return on the first TABLE A

```
1,2017-026221,001,BAD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,002,BAD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,003,BAD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,004,BAD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,005,BAD description,..... VERY LAST
```

EXAMPLE Data return on the first TABLE B

```
1,null,XX1,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,null,XX2,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,null,XX3,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,null,XX4,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,null,XX5,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
```

EXAMPLE RETURN Data return, basically first TABLE A with one value on TABLE B

```
1,2017-026221,001,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,002,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,003,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,004,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
1,2017-026221,005,GOOD description,..... VERY LAST
```

### Assume

- `Script Table As` is a solution to auto fill the column, but is not going to fit for the need.  The solution of the
  question should not include the opposite of the question's request to
  not list the columns as stated in the title.
- A solution that requires GRANTS that will let you read the system table are not allowed in many cases.

## Solution as of yet

It is starting to sound like the answer is there may not be another way to do what I did with out listing all columns out.  If it doesn't turn out to be the case then I'll remove this section.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i updated, please let me know if that clears it up

Comment: Are you asking only to avoid typing all the column names, or is there some other good reason to prefer using `SELECT *` over an explicit column list?

Comment: Let us assume that there are 50 columns and I am avoiding typing it out :D .. the basic need to to be super 100% clear to everyone else in the DB what is going on, and it is way to easy to get lost in that mess of columns on a tradition select here.  More over, it will be something that is plugged in to some other things so I am just look for a different way to write what i did, with out listing every column.  Hope that clears it up.  What i have works fine, but I was hoping for something that may be a little more "native"

Comment: If you are using SQL Server Management Studio, you could select your query, with the *, right click on it and choose "Design Query In Editor".  All of the columns will be selected in the designer.  Click OK and your * will be replaced with all of your column names, without having to type them out manually.

Comment: Ok, your latest edit has made this question a matter of opinion.   You think that what you've done is more "readable" than a SELECT with the columns written out because it fills up the screen?   I disagree.   Opinions vary.  You also seem to feel that a query that takes up less space on the screen is "better" than a query that performs well but takes up more space on the screen.

Comment: @TabAlleman Woooo dude chill... not needed.  I asked a very specific question, here is a query that does this, is there any other way to do it with out listing the other columns.  opinion is being injected here, I have a need, and didn't say why because the why is unimportant, it is a matter of if there is another way or not.  Please have a wonderful day and thank you for taking the time to try and help it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is the only way to perform it using dynamic queries.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @temp_grouping nvarchar(max) = 'col1, col2, col3'
set @query = 'SELECT  '+@temp_grouping+' FROM [ae_p_phs_e] where [template_id] = ''1010'''
print @query
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Can you do that with out the dynamic SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't.

Comment: on this line `@temp_grouping nvarchar(max) = 'col1, col2, col3'`  would i not have to list out all 25 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your comment didn't really clarify what I'm trying to figure out, but let me go ahead and suggest a solution based on what I'm guessing you are trying to do.   Actually, I have two solutions, based on two guesses:

1. You want to write a SELECT from a table with a lot of columns, so you want to avoid typing out all the column names for no other reason than that it would be a lot of typing.  But you can't do a simple SELECT * because there is one column that you want to replace in the output with a column from another table.

Solution:  Right click on the table in the SSMS Object Explorer pane,  and choose Script Table As > SELECT To > New Query Window.

You will get a new query window with the SELECT query written out, with all the column names written out for you.  No typing required.   Then just modify that query with the JOIN you want, and find the column you want to replace in the SELECT list and replace it with the column from the JOINed table.  This produces the SELECT query you want on an adhoc basis.

2. You have a more fluid situation where you don't necessarily know, for whatever reason, what the columns are going to be, so therefore you can't hard-code a column list, but you know that if a certain column appears, you want to replace it with a different one.

Solution: use a dynamic sql query, like the one in Rainman's answer.  Instead of typing out the column list, like you mention in  your comment to his answer, you can dynamically generate that list by querying the system tables to get all the columns belonging to the table you are interested in.

Comment: oh, I think if I can write what is above, I think it would be clear I would know how to right click and how to use a join.. ;) all in good fun there.  The point is not if i can fill the screen with all the columns.